# What are the types of Xpath expressions for web application automation

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

What types of Xpath expressions can I use when automating web applications?

I need to know different ways of finding elements so that if I can't use an ID I can always locate the element I need to work with.

*Note: This is intended to be a canonical question about Xpath expressions.*

Comment: What was your problem?  from your own answered question, It seems that you have just posted this question for knowledge sharing. I don't know How others will react on this post..but I think this is not a good practice here...

Comment: Please refer this:
https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: The concept of asking a question and then answering it is fine here. These tend to be considered canonical questions to build a good knowledge base. Unfortunately, this question will need a lot of editing to make a good canonical question. I will do that next.

Comment: Nice editing @KatePaulk to avoid from closing this post.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort for working on this @KatePaulk. People like you make this community glow brighter.

Comment: Question should mention that XPath is locator of the last resort, when name, ID, CSS class etc cannot be used, because it is fragile and flaky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Xpath Types**

***•Xpath using contains text***

```
//div[contains(text(),'Sign up')]
```

***•Xpath using text***

```
//div[ (text()='Sign up')]
```

***•Merge Xpath (combining two Xpaths together)***

```
Xpath=(//input[@name='email'])[2]/div/div/a
```

***•We can use multiple attributes inside the Xpaths***

```
//input[@id='email'][@name='email']
```

**•We can also use logical expressions like 'AND' 'OR' in an XPath expression**

```
//input[@name='email' and @type='Phone']

//input[@name='email' or @type='Phone']
```

***•Xpath using following, preceding***

```
//table[@role='presentation']/following::input 

//table[@role='presentation']/following-sibling::input

//table[@role='presentation']/ preceding::input

//table[@role='presentation']/ preceding-sibling::input
```

Comment: You can indeed write `@value='Email or Phone'` but it means something quite different from `@value='Email' or @value = 'Phone'`

Comment: yes, you are correct. I'll change the attribute values. Thank you.

Comment: @KavinduWije, Excellent, thanks for sharing the knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few addons for Firefox that can make your life easier when it comes to locators.

I use Mozilla [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-locator-for-webdriv/).

[image: screen shot]